# how to uninstall a CPU miner?

Tags: uninstall

I am newby and installed a CPU miner in my computer and now i want to uninstall it with all packages.
And of course i don't want to harm any other system.
[watch this on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xEZ4ZD8HSx8) <virtualcoin.videos@gmail.com>
and during the installation i followed these steps:

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get install docker.io
# docker pull virtualcoin/cpuminer
# docker run --rm -it virtualcoin/cpuminer monero
```

Anyone can help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: I just fixed the formatting on your post but I wasn't sure where the email address was supposed to go, so I just put it in verbatim. Please correct it if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to askubuntu.com! You installed only docker which is a container virtualization tool. There is nothing to remove apart from the image you pulled: `docker rmi virtualcoin/cpuminer`

Optionally, you can remove the docker too (which does nothing by itself): `apt-get remove docker.io`